# Why do we say "right-hand side"?

Tags: phrases, differences

This question is in reference to the use of the word "hand" in "right-hand side" (and applies equally to the left).

**My question is what does "right-hand side" say/imply that "right side" doesn't?**

Comment: If you mean this question to apply to "left/left-hand" as well, you will need to say so. "Why do we insert *hand* into these phrases when it's superfluous?"

Comment: It gets worse when people refer to right-hand and left-hand pedals...

Comment: Because they're superfluous idiots that want to be slapped with your right hand hand.

Comment: Does anyone think it could have something to do with the cadence in "right-hand side"? In "right side" there is a longer pause between the words. Consider also for instance the fact that people tend to say, "Where's it at?" and not "Where's it?"

Comment: because language naturally contains lots of [redundancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_%28information_theory%29) to ensure a good signal-to-noise ratio.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suppose that *hand* is used to distinguish from *right* as in *correct*.

Comment: By that logic, we use _hand_ on the other side, too, to distinguish from _left_ as in _remaining_. :^)

Comment: @J.R. oooh!  Yes.

Comment: Or these days, to remove the political connotation

Comment: @J.R. Reminds me of the epic wordplay, "War decides not who is right, but who is left."

Answer (score 7):

Handedness is perhaps the most common way of teaching someone *left* from *right*.  While there are other natural things that exhibit consistant directionality (the circular flow of water in a drain in a given hemisphere; the rotation of the earth when seen from above a particular pole, etc.) none is as readily accessible to the viewer as her or his own handedness. Most of us know from an early age which of our hands is dominant, and that is labeled by our elders as either *right* or *left*, depending on our proclivities (let's skip the brain dominance discussion for now).

We can then identify whether the direction or side we are considering corresponds to *our* right or left side, based on our knowledge of our dominant hand.

I think the *hand* reference when discussing *side* is a reflection (residual) of this basic analysis we learned in our youth.

Comment: Not all cultures have "right" and "left".  Some refer exclusively to geographic direction, like "your north hand", which changes depending on which direction you're facing.

Comment: @endolith That's very interesting. Which cultures? And what happens when you are facing north or south?

Comment: it would become your "east hand" or "west hand" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_direction#Cultures_not_using_relative_directions http://www.nytimes.com/2010/08/29/magazine/29language-t.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0  or other cultures use "uphill" and "downhill"? http://geo-mexico.com/?p=3680

Comment: @bib "Which cultures?" 9 years late but: the Aboriginal Australian _Guugu Yimithirr_ people of Hopevale in Queensland, whose language is also called _Guugu Yimithirr_. See _[Guugu Yimithirr Cardinal Directions](https://pages.ucsd.edu/~jhaviland/Publications/ETHOSw.Diags.pdf)_.

Answer (score 2):

I always thought right/left hand side was used instead of right/left side so you could be clear about a location.

For example, when something is on the right hand side of the dresser, if you are facing the dresser, it will be to your right, not on the actual right side of the dresser from its point of view, facing you.

Comment: Good point. You could think of it as being opposite of "stage right/left", the right/left as viewed from the subject looking towards you.

Bojack Horseman: "Okay, move it to the left a little ... I meant *stage* left. See, I'm a famous actor..."

Answer (score 1):

My husband and I have been 'discussing' this for years.  If you look at a 'thing', e.g. car or boat, the right or starboard side of the boat is on the left hand side as you face the boat, but it is still the right side of the boat.  I say the right side of the boat is always the right side.  Key word is 'OF' - the side belongs to the boat.  Same with a piece of furniture, etc., but as you face a piece of furniture, the left hand side is relative to the person facing the furniture.  Same with N, S, E, and W on a map.  E is on the left side OF the map but it is on the left hand side as one faces it.

Answer (score 0):

Its based on perspective. When you say Right-Hand side, you imply that it is your perspective, versus right side, which could be either

Comment: Surely then you should say "my right-hand side" to be clear since, presumably, the person you're talking to also has a right hand.